# React Native - Change Curve Direction

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a donut pie chart in react-native where curve should be in clock direction. I achieved most of it to fulfil the requirement using plugin https://github.com/nihgwu/react-native-pie but I am not finding a way to change the direction.

If anyone has played around with this component then please suggest the code changes to meet the expected UI.

**Code:**

```js
        <Pie
          radius={100}
          innerRadius={80}
          series={[40, 0.5, 30, 0.5, 20, 0.5, 10, 0.5, 0]}
          colors={['red', 'white', 'green', 'white', 'orange', 'white', 'blue', 'white', 'red']}
          backgroundColor="white"
          strokeCap="round"
        />
```

Current:

[image: Anti-Clock Direction]

Expected:
[image: Clock Direction]

Comment: Following functionality has been added by our team in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pie